# Let a be a positive real number and let $M_a=\{z \in C^* : |z+\frac{1}{z}|=a\}$ Find the minimum....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Problem : 
Let a be a positive real number and let $M_a=\{z \in C^* : |z+\frac{1}{z}|=a\}$ Find the minimum and maximum value of $|z|$ when $z \in M_a$

My approach :

$|z+\frac{1}{z}|=a$

Squaring both sides we get :

$\Rightarrow |z+\frac{1}{z}|^2=a^2$

$ \Rightarrow (z+\frac{1}{z})(\overline{z}+\frac{1}{\overline{z}}) =|z|^2+\frac{z^2+(\overline{z})^2}{|z|^2}+\frac{1}{|z|^2}$

$\Rightarrow |z|^4-|z|^2.(a^2+2)+1 = -(z+\overline{z})^ \leq 0$

Now how to approach further please suggest will be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$|z+\frac{1}{z}|=a$

$\Rightarrow |\frac{1}{z} (z^2 +1)|=a$

$\Rightarrow |z^2 +1|=a |z|$

$\Rightarrow |z^2 +1|^2=a^2 |z|^2$

Writing $z = r e^{i \theta}$ with $r>0$, the problem is to find the extremal values of $r$.

$\Rightarrow |r^2 e^{2i\theta} +1|^2=a^2r^2$

$\Rightarrow (1+r^2 \cos(2 \theta))^2 + r^4 \sin(2 \theta)^2 = a^2r^2$

$\Rightarrow r^4 + (2 \cos(2 \theta)-a^2) r^2 + 1 = 0 $

With the change of variable $X = r^2$ you get a quadratic equation in $X$:

$X^2 + \lambda X + 1 = 0$ with $\lambda=2 \cos(2 \theta)-a^2$

Solving this equation should give you the possible values of $r = |z|$.